# SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException in OWIN OpenID Connect middleware connecting to Google

Tags: google-oauth, owin, identityserver3, openid-connect

We are using the generic OpenID Connect middleware to use Google as an external identity provider using IdentityServer3. We don't have MetadataAddress or any special TokenValidationParameters set up (so it should be getting the metadata based on Authority, and then filling in parameters based on that, which should be fine). We are getting the following error highly intermittently. Other questions I've come up with that have this error seem to involve incorrect custom validation and are not intermittent.

```
Authentication Failed : Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectMessage : System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException : IDX10500 : Signature validation failed.Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier : 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
(
IsReadOnly = False,
Count = 1,
Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
)
',
token : '{"alg":"RS256","kid":"74e0db263dbc69ac75d8bf0853a15d05e04be1a2"}.{"iss":"https://accounts.google.com","iat":1484922455,"exp":1484926055, <snip more claims>}'.
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)in c :  \ workspace \ WilsonForDotNet45Release \ src \ System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt \ JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs : line 943
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken & validatedToken)in c :  \ workspace \ WilsonForDotNet45Release \ src \ System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt \ JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs : line 671
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions.SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionExtensions.ValidateToken(SecurityTokenHandlerCollection tokenHandlers, String securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken & validatedToken)in c :  \ workspace \ WilsonForDotNet45Release \ src \ Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions \ SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionExtensions.cs : line 71
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler. < AuthenticateCoreAsync > d__1a.MoveNext()
```

The `kid` referred to is presently the 2nd of 3 keys at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs.

Our Options look like this:

```
var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationType = "Google",
                    Caption = "Sign in with Google",
                    Scope = "openid email profile",
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = "https://accounts.google.com/",
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                    RedirectUri = new Uri(baseUri, "identity/signin-google").ToString(),
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = context => HandleException(context),
                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = context => AddLoginHint(context),
                    },
                    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType
                };

                app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
```

Is this a configuration issue or some sort of transient error that needs to be dealt with (and if so how)? The end client is doing one retry (though I don't think it's waiting at all) but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to have been caused by the fact that the default [ConfigurationManager](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev4x/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs) caches results for 5 days, while Google rolls over their keys much more frequently (more like daily). With the default behavior of the OWIN middleware, the first request with an unrecognized key will fail, and then on the next request it will refresh the keys.

The solution is to pass in your own ConfigurationManager with a faster AutomaticRefreshInterval. Most of the settings below are as in [OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware.cs)

```
private static void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {
        var baseUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44333");
        var googleAuthority = "https://accounts.google.com/";
        var metadataAddress = googleAuthority + ".well-known/openid-configuration";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler());
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10 MB
        var configMgr = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(metadataAddress, httpClient)
                            {
                                // Default is 5 days, while Google is updating keys daily
                                AutomaticRefreshInterval
                                    =
                                    TimeSpan
                                    .FromHours(12)
                            };

        var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                          {
                              AuthenticationType = "Google",
                              Caption = "Google",
                              Scope = "openid email profile",
                              ClientId = GoogleClientId,
                              Authority = googleAuthority,
                              ConfigurationManager = configMgr,
                              AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                              RedirectUri =
                                  new Uri(baseUri, "identity/signin-google").ToString(),
                              SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType
                          };

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
    }
```