# Verify RS256 Signed JWT Token using OWIN JWT Bearer Authentication

Tags: model-view-controller, jwt, owin

We have several .NET Framework 4.6.1 MVC applications that use OWIN to setup authentication. We want to us the UseJwtBearerAuthentication option with a JWT token that was signed using RS256.

We also have the Public Key needed to verify the JWT Token. It is retrieved by an API call and is received as a JSON Web Key Set (JWKS) JSON string.

SAMPLE JWKS from https://auth0.com/docs/jwks

```
{
"keys": [
{
"alg": "RS256",
"kty": "RSA",
"use": "sig",
"x5c": [
  "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"
],
"n": "yeNlzlub94YgerT030codqEztjfU_S6X4DbDA_iVKkjAWtYfPHDzz_sPCT1Axz6isZdf3lHpq_gYX4Sz-cbe4rjmigxUxr-FgKHQy3HeCdK6hNq9ASQvMK9LBOpXDNn7mei6RZWom4wo3CMvvsY1w8tjtfLb-yQwJPltHxShZq5-ihC9irpLI9xEBTgG12q5lGIFPhTl_7inA1PFK97LuSLnTJzW0bj096v_TMDg7pOWm_zHtF53qbVsI0e3v5nmdKXdFf9BjIARRfVrbxVxiZHjU6zL6jY5QJdh1QCmENoejj_ytspMmGW7yMRxzUqgxcAqOBpVm0b-_mW3HoBdjQ",
"e": "AQAB",
"kid": "NjVBRjY5MDlCMUIwNzU4RTA2QzZFMDQ4QzQ2MDAyQjVDNjk1RTM2Qg",
"x5t": "NjVBRjY5MDlCMUIwNzU4RTA2QzZFMDQ4QzQ2MDAyQjVDNjk1RTM2Qg"
}
]}
```

I want to use the OWIN framework for authentication with the UseJwtBearerAuthentication option. I found this sample code that goes in the startup.cs file that should work, but I can't figure out how to convert the JWKS to one of the constructors for a new X509Certificate2 object.

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
  new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
  {
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
    {
      new X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, new X509Certificate2("PATH_TO_YOUR_PUBLIC_CERTIFICATE.cer")),
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer here [Owin middleware for Bearer Token Authentication that supports JWT key rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040256/owin-middleware-for-bearer-token-authentication-that-supports-jwt-key-rotation)

I followed the example in the answer from @Padraic Hickey to create a custom IssuerSigningKeyResolver

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at any of the [Auth0 quickstarts](https://auth0.com/docs)?  The OWIN Web API quickstart seems to get something close to what you're after.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/webapi-owin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That does look promising.

Comment: So this appears to get me closer, but the OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver appears to only work for Auth0 issued Public Keys. We are using a different provider. I guess we'll have to write our own  IssuerSigningKeyResolver.